# Generate SQL script to create or alter table / stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am creating a SQL script that will check weather the object is there or not and then do create or alter based on that.

```
if not exists (select * from sysobjects where name='MyTableName' and xtype='U')
    create table MyTableName(
        Id int not null,
        Name varchar(150) not null
    )
Else
  --Alter
```

Now having to do this for a bigger database which has more than 150 table.

Is there any way I can generate this automatically for tables and stored procedures?

Comment: I don't understand. Will you create the same table everytime? or add same fields to an already existing table everytime?

Comment: @Shaharyar: Basically It will create only first time or run on a different server. Otherwise alter. Mainly script is for Stored Procedures as they get change frequently

Comment: @mrTester, I'd say that if you're expecting to get easy solution for alter-tables then you're in trouble. For SPs there is nothing interesting actually.

Comment: @IvanStarostin : The idea was to been able to run the same script over and over if needed without doing modification.

Comment: Why? What do you want to solve with this? What is the REAL problem?

Comment: @mrTester if script is always the same then what alterations of tables could there be?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can judge: Your question already includes the anser - NO it can not be done! The Thing is this: you COULD spool the metadata of tables etc. IF the objects existed in an Environment... as you arleady mentioned this is not the case - so how should a function / script / procedure be able to KNOW which columns etc. have to be created for which Table? Or what has to be altered if the table already existed?